# Sampling data in R

Tags: sampling, data-generation

I would like to sample 100x5 data points from the following format: 
With probability 0.6, 2. Otherwise (with probability 0.4, 10 + Epsilon) 
Epsilon ~ {-2,-1,0,1,2}

Here is what I did,

```
data.frame(sapply(1:5, function(x) sample(c(2,10 +sample(-2:2,1)), 100, prob=c(0.6, 0.4),replace=T)))
```

But it does not work. It samples the "sample(-2:2,1)" only once for each of the columns..

What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I found one simple solution for this particular case:

```
data.frame(sapply(1:5, function(x) sample(c(2,8,9,10,11,12), 100, prob=c(0.6, 0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08),replace=T)))
```

But what is a more general solution. For example if the Epsilon is from continuous distribution?